# Gsuite automatically add contact from email sender

Tags: gmail, contacts, google-workspace-for-business

I've been using Gmail for at least 10 years, Google Apps for at least 5.

Recently I noticed that people I email with are no longer added to my address book. I noticed this because I have to add them manually to my phone address book.

I'm pretty sure this worked at some point in the past. Is this something that has been turned off at some point or possibly an issue in my phone configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about G Suite, but in the plain old ordinary Gmail, that settings is under `Settings > General`.

> Create contacts for auto-complete:

Your two options are:

- When I send a message to a new person, add them to Other Contacts so that I can auto-complete to them next time
- I'll add contacts myself

I expect the options in G Suite are similar, unless your Administrator has turned it off for you.

Comment: I can confirm the options in G Suite are very similar. There are few options that the Admin could turn off but this is not one of them.

Comment: At this time the Gmail Help is the same for all the Gmail editions (Consumer, Google Apps Legacy, all the G-Suite variants). Related help article: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1069522?hl=en. Would you like that I contribute to your answers by including this kind of notes?